# Parallel ForEach Giving different results in different ocasions

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have never used `Parallel.ForEach` but I played around with it and found this occurrence.

I run a parallel loop (code found on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997393(v=vs.110).aspx did edit it with the `subtotal *=2` to try understand what it is doing) with an enumerable range firstly `(0,1)` and then `(0,1,2)` then I run the second one again but after sleeping the thread for 200 milliseconds, and the result then differs

if the `Thread.sleep(200)`is not commented out this is the results

```
result 1 = 2
result 2 = 6
result 3 = 4
```

if the `Thread.sleep(200)`is commented out this is the results

```
result 1 = 2 
result 2 = 6
result 3 = 6
```

Here is the code

```
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).ToArray();
long total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
     timer.Restart();
     total = 0;
     if (i == 0) nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).ToArray();
     if (i == 1) nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 2).ToArray();
     Parallel.ForEach<int, long>(nums,() => 0,(j, loop, subtotal) =>
     {
       subtotal += 1;
       subtotal *= 2;
       return subtotal;
     },(finalResult) => Interlocked.Add(ref total, finalResult)); 

     Console.WriteLine("The total from Parallel.ForEach is {0:N0} and took {1}", total, timer.Elapsed);
     timer.Stop();
     //Thread.Sleep(200);
}

timer.Restart();
nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 2).ToArray();
total = 0;
Parallel.ForEach<int, long>(nums, () => 0,  (j, loop, subtotal) =>
{
    subtotal += 1;
    subtotal *= 2;
    return subtotal;
},(finalResult) => Interlocked.Add(ref total, finalResult)); 

Console.WriteLine("The total from Parallel.ForEach is {0:N0} and took {1}", total, timer.Elapsed);
timer.Stop();
```

I figured it has got to do with threads working over one another but this seems like a bug

Note I did have a look at [Simulation gives different result with normal for loop Vs Parallel For](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944915/simulation-gives-different-result-with-normal-for-loop-vs-parallel-for?rq=1) 
Why is this happening?

Comment: @JánЯabčan Can you please elaborate. I dont understand what this code is doing when is it multiplying 2 and why?

Comment: I don't even understand how you get your results...

Comment: @sam change your thread.sleep to 1000 and see if you get it then

Comment: i don't understand what variable should i watch to see the results 2,6,4 or 2,6,6

Comment: @sam copy this code in a console application and run it... it is the total variable. if you are stepping through the code you are creating your own thread.sleep which means you will never see the 2,6,6 result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this code is ill-defined:

```
 Parallel.ForEach<int, long>(nums,() => 0,(j, loop, subtotal) =>
 {
   subtotal += 1;
   subtotal *= 2;
   return subtotal;
 },(finalResult) => Interlocked.Add(ref total, finalResult));
```

In that, if a *single* thread executes both iterations then you get the result 6. Effectively, you do:

```
subTotal = 0; //From init
subTotal += 1; //=1 First iteration
subTotal *= 2; //=2 First iteration
subTotal += 1; //=3 Second iteration
subTotal *= 2; //=6 Second iteration
total += subTotal; //=6 End gathering (actually interlocked)
```

But if two threads share the work, you get

```
subTotal1 = 0; //From init
subTotal2 = 0; //From init
subTotal2 += 1; //=1
subTotal1 += 1; //=1
subTotal1 *= 2; //=2
subTotal2 *= 2; //=2
total += subTotal1 //=2 End gathering 1 (interlocked)
total += subTotal2 //=4 End gathering 2 (interlocked)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. so just to make sure i understand this correctly parallel foreach should never be used for calculations it is then used where each iteration has its own execution not for values that get sent to the next iteration?

Comment: @Neil - I'm not sure what your question is. But, if you're using a variant of `Parallel.ForEach` that uses local state, a function that mutates local state and a final action that gathers all results and merges them, it only makes sense to do so if you'll get consistent results irrespective of how many threads are operating (so how many copies of the local state will exist) and how the results are merged in the final action. You had a calculation that doesn't work like that - it's critical in how many threads are being used and hence how many copies of local state exist.

Comment: That is what i was asking :). thank you for your answer and clarification. up-voted and accepted

Comment: @neil you *could* write one that does that (I've seen people do it in production code), but there is no point since you'd essentially be forcing it to be de facto single threaded.

Comment: @Taekahn Yeah that makes sense. this is what i understood on Damien's explanation

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever one last question. if i would to use this concept  to call a webservice for each client and the server could manage those in-sync requests and responses, the threads will be able to isolate and independently manage each cllients information?